# Xamarin Android FFImageLoading ImageService.Instance.LoadUrl() System.NullReferenceException

Tags: c#, android, xamarin, xamarin.android, ffimageloading

I've got a strange problem with **FFImageLoading**. Compiler don't show any error, but while application is starting on device, there is thrown an exception:
**System.NullReferenceException**.

---

Code:

**C#**

```
private void setUserImage()
{
    ImageService.Instance.Initialize();
    imgThunbailUsername = FindViewById<ImageViewAsync>(Resource.Id.imgDisplay);
    string url = @"https://lh4.googleusercontent.com/-Lfgi-xEMwuk/VNWoy8EDWcI/AAAAAAAAACk/rwsluNfhSZY/w1486-h832-no/photo.jpg";

    ImageService.Instance.LoadUrl(url)
        .Retry(3, 200)
        .DownSample(60, 60)
        .Into(imgThunbailUsername); // compiler points here with an exception
}
```

**XML**

```
<FFImageLoading.Views.ImageViewAsync
  android:id="@+id/imgDisplay"
  android:layout_width="fill_parent"
  android:layout_height="fill_parent"
  android:scaleType="fitCenter" />
```

---

I'd be thankful for any tip, idea, or even another good tool for images in Xamarin.

Comment: Have you debugged it? Is `imgThunbailUsername` null?

Comment: Well... I wont even comment it... Didn;t check it. It seems like compiler doesn't see any problem with it, but in real it doesn't find that element. Thank you. If you post your answer I'd accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay, I found out what's wrong. XML below is not directly under ViewModel.

```
<FFImageLoading.Views.ImageViewAsync
  android:id="@+id/imgDisplay"
  android:layout_width="fill_parent"
  android:layout_height="fill_parent"
  android:scaleType="fitCenter" />
```

XML over there is called inside

```
<android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
  android:layout_width="wrap_content"
  android:layout_height="match_parent"
  android:layout_gravity="start"
  android:background="@android:color/white"
  android:id="@+id/nav_view"
  app:headerLayout="@layout/drawer_header" <!-- here -->
  app:menu="@menu/navmenu" />
</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

So in this case I have to call properly view:

```
View headerLayout = navigationView.InflateHeaderView(Resource.Layout.drawer_header);
```

and so on use `FindViewById`like that:

```
imgThunbailUsername = headerLayout.FindViewById<ImageViewAsync>(Resource.Id.imgDisplay);
```

So all I need to do is just get a `View headerlayout` with `InflateHeaderView`.