# How to implement ffimageloading in xamarin android? (Native code)

Tags: c#, xamarin.android

I'm beginner in xamarin android. 
I want to display a set of images like FlowListview in xamarin android.
I used the following code in axml.I used this link [Xamarin Android FFImageLoading ImageService.Instance.LoadUrl() System.NullReferenceException](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43649799/xamarin-android-ffimageloading-imageservice-instance-loadurl-system-nullrefere).
But its not binding images like flowlistview

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:minWidth="25px"
    android:minHeight="25px" >
<FFImageLoading.Views.ImageViewAsync
  android:id="@+id/imgDisplay"
  android:layout_width="fill_parent"
  android:layout_height="fill_parent"
  android:scaleType="fitCenter" />
 </LinearLayout>
```

here is my c# code

```
  public class FlowListActivity : Activity
    {
        ImageViewAsync imgThunbailUsername;

        protected override void OnCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
        {
            base.OnCreate(savedInstanceState);
            SetContentView(Resource.Layout.FlowListLayout);
            setUserImage();
        }

        private void setUserImage()
        {
            ImageService.Instance.Initialize();
            imgThunbailUsername = FindViewById<ImageViewAsync>(Resource.Id.imgDisplay);
            string url = @"https://lh4.googleusercontent.com/-Lfgi-xEMwuk/VNWoy8EDWcI/AAAAAAAAACk/rwsluNfhSZY/w1486-h832-no/photo.jpg";

            for(int i=0;i<3;i++)
            {
                ImageService.Instance.LoadUrl(url)
               .Retry(3, 200)
               .DownSample(60, 60)
               .Into(imgThunbailUsername);
            }
           // compiler points here with an exception
        }
    }
```

[image]

Comment: Is it correct, that you are currently showing one imageview with the image? And you want to show a grid with several imageviews with this image?

Comment: The images are coming from a list.So the number of images is not predictable.

Comment: Sure thing - but currently, it seems like you are not using a "ListView" or a "RecyclerView" to show any list, representing a list of items?

Comment: are you using  a listview or recycler?

Comment: Can you share the code..I'm a beginner.And i dont have much more idea about this.